# How to edit php code to insert string multiple="multiple" for dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a dropdown with Regular select. I need a dropdown with Multiselect. 
I added the js script in header.php, now I need add string `multiple="multiple"`.

> In firebug I multiple = "multiple" in a string 
>   http://gyazo.com/e324c9bdcdd1d89cd3c78ba947145e68

Now I need add string `multiple="multiple"` in to this block but I don't know how do this:

```php
<?php wp_editor( get_the_content() , 'post_content' ); ?>
<?php 
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID,"listing_category" );
  $terms = isset($terms[0]) ? $terms[0]->term_id : "";

  if(get_field("custom_attributes_input_types","options") == "Dropdowns"):
    wp_dropdown_categories( 
      array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'listing_category', 
        'hierarchical'=>1, 
        'show_option_none'=>__('Choose Category:','um_lang'), 
        'name' => 'listing_category', 
        'hide_empty' => false, 
        'selected' => $terms
      )
    );
  else:
?>
```

Comment: Try the [wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/), you might have more luck there. I'm assuming this is for a wordpress site, it looks like wordpress code from what is posted.

Comment: Or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/